# return the difference from a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, return

I'm trying to compare the values of my dictionary and display my results like this.

Field Values Mismatch For Field: Expected:001 Actual:002

Field Values Mismatch For Field: Expected:003 Actual:002

I'm able to get the difference for each of the rows in my dictionary but I'm not sure how to display my result in string list.

This is what I have try

```
public static string ValidateMvpFields(string value1, Dictionary<string, ValueMap> value2)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(value1);

            foreach (var item in value2.Keys)
            {
                try
                {
                    var Val1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(responseParameters[item].XPath).InnerText;
                    var Val2 = responseParameters[item].Value;
                    if (!Val1.Trim().Equals(Val2.Trim()))
                    {
                        var results = ErrorMessage = $"Mvp Field Values Mismatch For Field: {item} Expected:{Val1} Actual:{Val2}";
                        string result = null;
                        result += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);
                    }
                    continue;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var results = ErrorMessage = $"Invalid Xpath: {value2[item].XPath} For Field:{item} Error:{ex.Message}";
                    /*return results*/
                    ;

                }
            }

            return "";


        }
```

Here is an example of my dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, ValueMap> Example = new Dictionary<string, ValueMap>
                  {
                    {"Example1", new ValueMap { XPath = "", Value = "5123"} },
                    {"Example2", new ValueMap { XPath ="", Value = "123"} },
}
```

Comment: Hi Mayi007, is there any updates on this?

Comment: I change my code with your suggestions and it works. Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad that my solution works for you, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing `string result = null` inside for loop, Initialize `StringBuilder` outside of `for` loop and append each result to it.

Initialization of `string result = null` everytime is creating new string variable every time and you are unable to get previously stored result while iterating inside for loop.

```
public static string ValidateMvpFields(string value1, Dictionary<string, ValueMap> value2)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(value1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  //Initialize StringBuider

        foreach (var item in value2.Keys)
        {
            try
            {
                var Val1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(responseParameters[item].XPath).InnerText;
                var Val2 = responseParameters[item].Value;
                if (!Val1.Trim().Equals(Val2.Trim()))
                {
                    var results = ErrorMessage = $"Mvp Field Values Mismatch For Field: {item} Expected:{Val1} Actual:{Val2}";
                    //Append new value every time into string builder
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(results);
                }
                continue;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var results = ErrorMessage = $"Invalid Xpath: {value2[item].XPath} For Field:{item} Error:{ex.Message}";
                /*return results*/
                ;

            }
        }

        return "";
    }
```

`string` type is immutable, when ever you assign new value to string it creates new object, `StringBuilder` is immutable so it helps to avoid memory leak.

If you want to store result in a list then use `List<string>` and add new result every time, like

```
   List<string> results = new List<string>(); //Initialize list
   ……
   results.Add(result);  //Add new value to it
```